# Why my navigation doesn't work in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have code that runs navigation in react native, unfortunately it doesn't work. Here's my code:

```
_postData() {
    if(this.state.email !== '' || this.state.password !== ''){
      const dataAkun = {
        email: this.state.email,
        password: this.state.password
      }
      const paramsData = new URLSearchParams();
      paramsData.append('email', this.state.email);
      paramsData.append('password', this.state.password);
      //AsyncStorage.setItem('akun', JSON.stringify(dataAkun));
      axios.post('http://radarugi.com/rekber/login.php', paramsData)
        .then(function (response) {
          const resultArray = JSON.stringify(response);
          const kitaParse = JSON.parse(resultArray);
          if(kitaParse.data.statusCode == '1'){
            Alert.alert('Berhasil login!');
            AsyncStorage.setItem('akun', kitaParse.data.keyResult);
            _updateData('akun', kitaParse.data.keyResult);
            this.props.navigation.navigate('HomeWelcome', {akun: kitaParse.data.keyResult});
          }else{
            Alert.alert('Email/Password salah!');
          }
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }else{
      Alert.alert('Mohon isi email dan password!');
    }
  }
```

when the function is run, it only issues the "Berhasil login!" alert, even though there is a command below to move to another screen.

```
Alert.alert('Berhasil login!');
AsyncStorage.setItem('akun', kitaParse.data.keyResult);
_updateData('akun', kitaParse.data.keyResult);
this.props.navigation.navigate('HomeWelcome', {akun: kitaParse.data.keyResult});
```

this is my stackNavigator code:

```
const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Welcome: LoginWelcome,
    RegisterWelcome: RegisterWelcome,
    HomeWelcome: Home,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Welcome',
    headerMode: 'none',
  }
);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(RootStack);
```

Comment: Could you put here the error you get?

Comment: I didn't get any errors

Comment: LOG  [TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props')]

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways you can fix this.

1. Assign this outside the callback then use it inside callback

```
_postData() {
    ...
    const that = this;
    axios.post('http://radarugi.com/rekber/login.php', paramsData)
        .then(function (response) {
            ...
            that.props.navigation.navigate('HomeWelcome', {akun: kitaParse.data.keyResult});
            ...
        })
    ...
}
```

2. Use arrow function as callback

```
_postData() {
    ...
    axios.post('http://radarugi.com/rekber/login.php', paramsData)
        .then((response) => {
            ...
            this.props.navigation.navigate('HomeWelcome', {akun: kitaParse.data.keyResult});
            ...
        })
    ...
}
```